Proof that $ALL_{DFA} \in SPACE(log^{2}n)$
we define $ALL_{DFA}$ as:
$ALL_{DFA} = \{ <A> | \text{ A is a DFA and L(A) = }\Sigma ^ {*} \}$
I'm looking for a proof that $ALL_{DFA} \in SPACE(log^{2}n)$ where n is the number of states in the DFA
I have noticed that $L(A) = \Sigma ^ {*} \iff$ the start state of A is an accepting state, and every state that is reachable from the start state is also an accepting state.
The problem is that I can't implement DFS from the start state because of the space complexity restriction
another idea that was proposed to me is to prove that $ALL_{DFA} \in NSPACE(logn)$ , and then by savitch's theorem we would get that $ALL_{DFA} \in SPACE(log^{2}n)$, but I can't think about a way to show that $ALL_{DFA} \in NSPACE(logn)$

In that case this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem

By the characterization that you noted, the complement of $\mathrm{ALL_{DFA}}$ is in $\mathrm{NL=NSPACE}(\log n)$ because directed $s$-$t$-connectivity is in $\mathrm{NL}$. Then apply Savitch’s theorem, using that $\mathrm{SPACE}\bigl((\log n)^2\bigr)$ is closed under complement.
(Actually, $\mathrm{ALL_{DFA}}$ is itself in $\mathrm{NL}$ as $\mathrm{NL}$ is closed under complement as well by the Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem, but that’s an overkill here.)
